# Fighter class does not implement interface member

Tags: c#, class, interface

And I am getting this error:

> Error 1   'Fight.Fighter' does not implement interface member
>   'Fight.IFighter.Utok(Fight.IFighter)'

This is the first time I am trying to learn working with interfaces, so sorry for dump question.

Any ideas?

I have following code:

Interface:

```
    interface IFighter
    {
        string GraphicLife();
        bool IsLive();
        int Obrana(int utocneCislo);
        void Utok(IFighter bojovnik);
    }
}
```

Class:

```
class Fighter : IFighter
{
    protected string name;
    protected int life;
    protected int maxLife;
    protected int attack;
    protected int defence;

    protected Kostka kostka;

    public Fighter(string name, int life, int maxLife, int attack, int defence, Kostka kostka){
        this.name = name;
        this.life = life;
        this.maxLife = maxLife;
        this.attack = attack;
        this.defence = defence;
        this.kostka = kostka;
    }

    public bool IsLive()
    {
        if (life > 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else return false;
    }

    public string GraphicLife()
    {
        int pozic = 20;
        int numberOfParts = (int)Math.Round(((double)life / (double)maxLife) * (double)pozic);
        string zivot = String.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("#", numberOfParts));
        zivot = zivot + String.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("_", pozic - numberOfParts));
        zivot = "[" + zivot + "]";
        return zivot;
    }

    public void Utok(Fighter warrior)
    {
        if (warrior.IsLive())
        {
            int utok = (int)Math.Round((double)attack / (double)kostka.getPocetStran() * (double)kostka.getNumber());
            int obrana = warrior.Obrana(utok);
            Console.WriteLine(this.name + "utoci na " + warrior.name + " silou " + utok + " " + warrior.name + " se brani silou " + obrana);
            Console.WriteLine(this.name + " - " + this.life);
            Console.WriteLine(this.GraphicLife());
            Console.WriteLine(warrior.name + " - " + warrior.life);
            Console.WriteLine(warrior.GraphicLife());
        }
        else Console.WriteLine(this.name + " utoci na mrtvolu");
    }

    public int Obrana(int attackNumber)
    {
        int localDefence = (int)Math.Round((double)defence/ (double)kostka.getPocetStran() * (double)kostka.getNumber());
        int utok = attackNumber - localDefence;
        if (utok < 0) utok = 0;
        life = life - utok;
        return localDefence;
    }

}}
```

Comment: Right click the interface in the class definition and select implement interface

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the concrete type *Fighter* in the parameter-list of your method instead of the abstract type *IFighter*.

Change the following line

```
public void Utok(Fighter warrior)
```

To

```
public void Utok(IFighter warrior)
```

You need to use the **exact type** defined in the interface if you implement it in a class.

If you define your interfaces before you create a class you (which is the most common way) you can use a nice helper provided by Visual Studio to do some of the work for you. Point your cursor to the interface-name and use "Implement interfaces"-function to automatically create method-stubs for your interfaces.

Edit:

You need to add the property "Name" to the interface as well to make it work. It has to be a property which needs at least a getter:

```
string name { get; }
```

A normal variable instead of a getter would not work here, because interfaces cannot contain variables.

Only the properties of the interface are available regardless how much classes actually implement that interface somewhere else in your application.

Answer (score 2):

Your method signature for `Utok` requires an instance of `IFighter` instead of `Fighter` as defined by your interface contract.

```
public void Utok(IFighter warrior)
{
    // ...
}
```

> To implement an interface member, the corresponding member of the implementing class must be public, non-static, and have the same name and **signature** as the interface member.

This means **exactly the same signature**.

Comment: @aruzkaty: That's because `IFighter` doesn't contain those things.  This sounds like a rabbit hole of Liskov Substitution problems.  If those are properties that any `IFighter` should expose then they should be added as properties to that interface.

Comment: I see, I thought that interface can contain just methods, not variables.

Comment: @aruzkaty: Correct.  Though properties are a kind of method.